# Spring Cloud ClassNotFoundException when trying to run Spring Cloud Kinesis

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

Recently I opened a brand new project with Spring Initializr within IntelliJ with the following dependencies.

```
    <properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR2</spring-cloud.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws-messaging</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-test-support</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

And modified the sample class with really simply code to just see how Spring Cloud works and check messages.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Processor.class)
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @StreamListener(Processor.INPUT)
    @SendTo(Processor.OUTPUT)
    public String readKinesis(byte[] message) {
        System.out.println(String.format("Reading message... Content -> %s", new String(message)));
        return new String(message);
    }

}
```

However, whenever I run the project the following error is shown.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageV3
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
... 37 common frames omitted
```

I've been also trying to execute sample projects within the `spring-cloud-stream-samples` but no luck so far, either because of `aws-vault` credentials (which, somehow, seem to work with my newly created project) or any other issue.

Also important to note that `spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis` has been manually added by me as the binder wasn't being found. Also create a `META-INF` directory with a `spring.binders` inside specifying it manually.

**EDIT**

Found the issue.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

For some reason, both libraries may not be able to live together within the same project. Should two different builds be required?

Comment: CNFE exceptions are pretty straight forward since they state exactly what is missing and by adding such dependency always solves the issue. So the above simply tells me you are missing https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.protobuf/protobuf-java. The real question is what's in your code that is requiring such dependency as it is not visible from what is posted.

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky believe me, all the code that is within the post is all the code within the project. It's a really really simple project just to launch and see how it goes, nothing complex. The only thing I can think of is `spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis` being the source of the problem, but then again, without a binder... How can I R/W from Kinesis?

Comment: I understand, that was pretty much an open question. Hopefully Artem Bilan will chime in soon

Comment: I don't see any relation to Kinesis Binder. You have a Google Cloud stuff on your classpath, but according the stack trace not all of them. Kinesis (or AWS) doesn't deal with Protobuf at all.

Comment: @ArtemBilan sorry for the late reply. Been checking dependencies and AWS is using Protobuf 3.x and Google Cloud using 2.x, so there's a mistmatch going on there. Forcing a Protobuf version solves the issue (at least at compile time). Will need to check whether that forcing still makes GCP to work.

Comment: Can you show, please, dependency tree where AWS brings  Protobuf?